# Android mobile works like Putty over bluetooth connection

Tags: android, ssh, bluetooth, android-inputtype

Is there a possibility to work on putty config using an android phone.? Like the mobile phone must be paired with a bluetooth device. Then the XML commands is send in putty terminal using your mobile and you are able to get the data from the bluetooth device??

Comment: chichi, I dont think so this is possible, because as I have searched I can not get anything related to this with Android.

Comment: Why wouldn't this be possible? You pair a device with bluetooth and afterwards it's just sending/receiving messages on a stream? (There's not a Putty* branded app for it though, you'd have to write your own like I did myself)

Comment: sir #gl77 i tried to pair a bluetooth SPP device and send a command   that my device accepts. I use BluetoothTerminal for example. I send the command in string. I supposed to receive a result but I dont get any... How can I get the data in a blluetooth device..? @gl77

Comment: I'm not familiar with BluetoothTerminal. I have written an own bluetooth app to test communication between SPP devices, so it's definitely possible. Are you sure your device doesn't requires an 'Terminator' to recognize the command?

Comment: Im really not sure,, but the device said that he must receive some XML Command which is already define in the sysmtem so he will gve the answer of the command requested. "using terminal in putty they wer able to receive a response from the device. I use bluetooterminal and paired with the device and send the string. i dont get any result. I dont have idea how ..

Comment: @ChichiDinoy Kindly dont use the word **SIR**

Comment: Okay Rajest, can you help me?